# How to set button click once a day

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing attendance system in which user login and mark attendance by clicking on button,after record insert into database(including today date) button get invisible but when user again login it again show and user can again mark attendance.I want that user can just click only once in a day even after they login again?

```
if (present.Checked)
{
    btnattendance.Visible = false;
    lblattend.Text = "Attendance has been Marked Succsessully" + " " + dateofclass1;

    return status1 = "Present";
}
else
{
    btnattendance.Visible = false;

    lblattend.Text = "Leave Request has been sent to Admin" + " " + dateofclass1;
    return status1 = "Leave";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. Store the 'click' event per user (with the time of clicking) into the database .
2. On page load; check if the user has clicked in the last 24 hours.
3. Activate the button if not.
4. Check again **on click**. People *can* edit the HTML to let them still be able to click the button (e.g. by removing the `disabled` state).

**Check if the time is 24 hours (or more) ago**

```
var lastClickedOn = ...; // The time from the database.
var now = DateTime.Now;

// Check if the click time is more than, or exactly, 24 hours ago.
if (lastClickedOn <= now.AddHours(-24))
{
    // Hide/disable the button
}
```

Comment: yes i am saving the click event by inserting date into database with datetime.now but i dont know how to write code to check whether the user clicked last 24 hours are not??

Comment: I've added an example, but please don't ask to "just write the code". Thats kinda rude.

Comment: this is what i am searching for last two days but at last you save my time thank you very much bro wish you meet once in my life :p .. little mistake in ur code actually disable button will be in the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

1. After user login is authenticated, your application logic should check whether the user is already marked attendance for the day.
2. if the attendance is already marked in a Database table, it should return a flag to client web app
3. your client web app logic can then decide whether to enable or disable attendance submission button based on the flag